# how to generate index with org-export?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Here the index is not the index.html for a website, but like the thing which tells you the position of a keyword in the book.

PS: export to HTML Format

Comment: I would suspect it would depend on which exporter you are using, and probably has nothing to do with Org-mode itself.  For example, if you are doing a LaTeX export, you probably just want to include a LaTeX package that makes an index for you; see, for example, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing

Comment: Use :makeindex, see org manual chapter 13

Answer (score 2):

Use `:makeindex` to generate a keyword index. You need some special typings in your org files.

In you org file, you need add lines in relevant position:

```
#+index: some-keyword
```

In you .emacs file, make sure your `org-publish-project-alist` has already turned on the  `:makeindex` option.

now, you can check the theindex.html for keyword indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:makeindex`, see [org manual chapter 13](https://orgmode.org/manual/Generating-an-index.html):

> 13.1.8 Generating an index
>
> Org mode can generate an index across the files of a publishing
>   project.
>
> ```
> :makeindex
> ```
>
> When non-nil, generate in index in the file ‘theindex.org’ and publish
>   it as ‘theindex.html’.
>
> The file is created when first publishing a project with the
>   :makeindex set. The file only contains a statement
>
> ```
> #+INCLUDE: "theindex.inc"`
> ```
>
> You can then build around this include statement by adding a title,
>   style information, etc.
>
> Index entries are specified with ‘INDEX’ keyword. An entry that
>   contains an exclamation mark creates a sub item.
>
> ```
> *** Curriculum Vitae
> #+INDEX: CV
> #+INDEX: Application!CV
> ```